# Can you please check this proof?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I have this question out of Spivak's Calculus. From the field axioms, I have to prove that, for non-zero real numbers $a$ and $b$ we have that $(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$.

So this is what I have, where $e$ is the multiplicative identity:
$$(ab)a^{-1}b^{-1} = (aa^{-1})(bb^{-1})$$
$$(ab)a^{-1}b^{-1}  = (e)(e)$$

$$(ab)a^{-1}b^{-1} = e$$
$$(ab)^{-1}(ab)a^{-1}b^{-1} = (ab)^{-1}(e)$$
$$(e)a^{-1}b^{-1} = (ab)^{-1}$$
$$a^{-1}b^{-1} = (ab)^{-1}$$

Is this proof correct, and is there any way to write it in a more formal way.

Comment: @SimpleArt "$e$" is a standard notation for the identity in a group . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah, I ought to know such things.

Comment: Are these supposed to be numbers, elements of an arbitrary ring, a commutative ring? It is not true for groups in general that $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$.

Comment: What kind of algebraic structure are we in? A field?

Comment: Only true in a structure with a commutativity property.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. This is over the field of real numbers

Answer (score 1):

I am not saying your method is completely right or wrong.

But first thing $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$

One method to prove.

\begin{align*}
(ab)^{-1}(ab) &= e \newline
(ab)^{-1}(ab)(b^{-1}) &= (e)(b^{-1}) \newline
(ab)^{-1}(a)(bb^{-1}) &= (b^{-1}) \newline
(ab)^{-1}(a)(e) &= (b^{-1}) \newline
(ab)^{-1}(a) &= (b^{-1}) \newline
(ab)^{-1}(a)(a^{-1}) &= (b^{-1})(a^{-1}) \newline
(ab)^{-1}(e) &= (b^{-1})(a^{-1}) \newline
(ab)^{-1} &= (b^{-1})(a^{-1}) \newline
\end{align*}